# Bash shell: Illegal number when comapring strings

Tags: bash, shell

I am getting an error when I do string compare. Basically I am extracting names from 2 different files and try to compare them. It doesn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

```
 while read slave_line
 do
      slave_col1=`echo $slave_line | cut -d " " -f2`
      slave_col2=`echo $slave_line | cut -d " " -f3`
      slave_col=`echo $slave_line | cut -d " " -f1`

      while read line
      do
          master_col1=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f2`
          master_col2=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f3`
          if [ "$slave_col2" -eq  "$master_col2" ]; then
              echo $slave_col2 $master_col2 $slave_line $line
              echo $slave_line $line>> $3
       fi
       done < $2
 done < $1
```

Comment: This is very inefficient way of comparing files. Try to explain what are your input files what you're doing then we can certainly help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You say you are doing a *string compare* but that would be `=`, the operator `-eq` is specifically for integer comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

As [already mentioned by Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686508/2698019) you're using `-eq` instead of `=` and I don't think that you're really comparing numbers.

Here is a better version of your script. I have used `read` instead of `cut` and I have also fixed your quoting.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r slave_col slave_col1 slave_col2 _
do
    while read -r _ master_col1 master_col2 _
    do
        if [ "$slave_col2" = "$master_col2" ]; then
            echo "$slave_col2 $master_col2 $slave_line $line"
            echo "$slave_line $line" >> "$3"
        fi
    done < "$2"
done < "$1"
```

But, [as already stated by anubhava in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18686439/bash-shell-illegal-number-when-comapring-strings/18687682#comment27526100_18686439) this method is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

In line you [compare string](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html), so you use `=` or `==` operator. The line after edit is `if [ "$slave_col2" =  "$master_col2" ]; then`.

Comment: @RashmiA.P: Edited to use string comparision operator.